# Is there a way to force a program to crash?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I know people usually want to stop a program from crashing but I'd like to do just the opposite: I'd like to force a program to crash.

Why I am doing this:
I would like to force crash a program and use it to create a humorous video for educational use.

Edit: Here's an example: I open MS Word, then I want to use a program to force MS Word to crash so I get "MS Word has stopped working..." Or "MS Word has crashed. Do you want to submit a report?"

Comment: Depends what you expect to see I suppose but ProcDump (Microsoft/Sysinternals) can be used to force a dump of a process and you can give it a number of conditions when to do it.

Comment: Are you building the program yourself, or you want some other program to crash?

Comment: @ShubhamKumar no it's an existing program.

Comment: If it's just a matter of creating a video,  the easiest approach might be to create a program that displays the screens and/or messages that you want.

Comment: @Scott Yes, I do need to create just a video but I would like to show myself interacting with the program. I guess I could cut the video of me using it, and merge it with a video of a fake program, but how would I go about making this fake program? It sounds like it would be time consuming.

Comment: I believe that it might be not-very-hard in Visual Basic, but don't take my word for it. I have a little bit of experience using VB for data processing; I know nothing about its ability to create windows.